# Why a variable is required to open files

Tags: python

I'm having a bit of a conceptual problem. For writing to the file "to_file", this works:

```
out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)
```

...but this doesn't:

```
(open(to_file, 'w')).write(indata)
```

In theory, shouldn't swapping out a variable's (out_file) definition for the variable itself produce the same result? I'm confused as to why the extra step of creating the variable is necessary.

Comment: Why do you think the other case won't work? Don't say it's the missing variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, your code will actually open and write to the file. However,...

In your second, single-line code, you now have no reference to the open file. Therefore you have no way to close it or do anything else with it.

Leaving a file open is a resource leak. If your program closes right away, Python will try to close the file just before ending. But Python could possible fail, for a variety of reasons. For example, the removable disk drive containing the file may be removed after you write to the file but before your program ends. That could make the file unreadable on the removable drive--and I have seen this happen. And if your program does not close right away, you have this extra resource hanging around that takes memory and other resources that need not be taken. If your program continues for a long time, the growing resources could slow down or stop the computer.

Even if your program will close right away, this is a bad habit to develop. You don't just want to write programs, you want to write code that will work well in a variety of situations. You may think "I will never use this code in a long-running program." Such declarations often turn out to be mistaken. Coding is difficult enough--don't make it harder for yourself. Avoid the "anti-pattern" of your second example.

There is a better pattern in Python for such things, [using the `with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). Read that link and use that pattern rather than either of your two examples.

```
with open(to_file, 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write(indata)
```

Those two lines opened the file, wrote the data to the file, then closed the file. If you want to do more with the file before it is closed, put that code in the indented section under the `with` statement.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7, both of your provided examples will work and write to the file.